# How to apply inputmask that get value from controller or javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.5, jquery-inputmask

I have inputmask that work perfectly if it get value by keypressed or input manually but what I cant do is when that input get value from controller or set by javasript

This is my input mask

```
$("#price, #sum").inputmask( "numeric", {
    radixPoint: ",",
    groupSeparator: ".",
    digits: 2,
    autoGroup: true,
    prefix: 'Rp. ',
    rightAlign: true,
    oncleared: function () { self.Value(''); }
});
```

This is my input that get value from controller

```
<input id="price" name="price" type="text" class="form-control text-right" value="{{$create->price}}" required autofocus>
```

And last is my javascript to inject value

```
$('#sum').val(sum);
```

How I apply inputmask to that 2 condition with javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to change that type of input to text, like this:

```
<input id="price" name="price" type="text" class="form-control text-right" value="{{$create->price}}" required autofocus>
```